# Stata Loop for a series of actions on three separate dta files

Tags: loops, stata, dta

I'm trying to create a loop within Stata to apply a series of actions (including a merge, replacing missing values, replacing a date variable, sorting, and saving) to 3 different dta files (menin.dta, Bmenin.dta, and nonBmenin.dta). Below I have copied how to complete these tasks without a loop, but I want to figure out how to loop this code for the sake of simplifying it.

```
use "C:\Users\Desktop\menin.dta",clear
merge 1:1 bene_id using Controls,nogenerate
replace menin= 0 if menin ==.
replace date= refdate if menin ==0 
sort bene_id
save "C:\Users\Desktop\menin2.dta",replace

use "C:\Users\Desktop\Bmenin.dta",clear
merge 1:1 bene_id using Controls,nogenerate
replace Bmenin= 0 if Bmenin ==.
replace date= refdate if Bmenin ==0 
sort bene_id
save "C:\Users\Desktop\Bmenin2.dta",replace

use "C:\Users\Desktop\nonBmenin.dta",clear
merge 1:1 bene_id using Controls,nogenerate
replace nonBmenin= 0 if nonBmenin ==.
replace date= refdate if nonBmenin ==0 
sort bene_id
save "C:\Users\Desktop\nonBmenin2.dta", replace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you ask for:

```
foreach data_name in menin Bmenin nonBmenin {
    use "C:\Users\Desktop\\`data_name'.dta", clear
    merge 1:1 bene_id using Controls, nogenerate
    replace `data_name'= 0 if `data_name' == .
    replace date = refdate if `data_name' == 0 
    sort bene_id
    save "C:\Users\Desktop/`data_name'2.dta", replace
}
```

Note that a `` ` `` is escaped if following immediately after a `\` so you need to either do `` \\` `` or `` /` ``. I used one of each in the code example above. Best practice is to only use `/` as that would make this code run on Linux and Mac computers as well, but then you would have to update your hard coded file path anyways.